# Consider the Stack Exchange app as a valid app to view Stack Overflow posts

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, stack-exchange, stack-overflow-app

I often view posts on my iPhone through the Google app or the browser because I prefer searching the web and don't like to be limited by Stack Overflow search results.

**There is this great feature** which *should* open the app for an improved experience. Unfortunately **it never worked for me**. Instead of opening the post in my app it kept redirecting me to the app store to download the app which I already had installed. The only way to view the post in my app was to copy the URL and paste it in the app's search box which then yielded the correct post. I believed that the store redirection must be a bug. Right?

Well, it isn't. Turns out I had the Stack Exchange app installed and the website requires the Stack Overflow app to be installed. From my perspective this is a use case that should be implemented because it looks like a bug from a user's perspective.

---

[image: Screenshot of misbehaviour]

Comment: I know you like the red circle in my image. Don't try to hide your excitement!

Comment: Charge your phone!!! :)

Comment: (Not) to start an all out Android vs iOS battle but on Android I get asked if I want to continue in the browser or if I want to open the app...

Comment: @Script47 the same is entirely possible on iOS, it's just the app doesn't implement it

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev ah, I never knew it had to be implemented. So you do learn something new everyday. Thanks. I'm curious why it's implemented for Android but not iOS?

Comment: i have similar/same problem. Only, the banner does nothing for me. I have the app installed on my iOS. I'm very sure it worked perfectly When I just got the app. However three months or so ago it stop and I just dealt with the annoyance down the road

Comment: @Script47 as far as I know, StackExchange's apps for iOS and Android are developed entirely independently and by different people

Comment: Strange. I’m on iOS and have never had this issue. Tapping the “read this post in our app” link opens the StackExchange app correctly and always has done.

Comment: @Andy That's interesting. Can you provide more info about your device and the running iOS? I'll modify this to a bug report once you provide the info :)

Comment: @NoelWidmer hmmm...looks like I spoke too soon. SO links definitely used to open in the SE app before the SO app was released. I tested a WordPress SE link this morning and that opened in the app correctly, but I just tried an SO link and it wants me to get the SO app. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Wait, you mean there is not only an SO app, but also a separate SE app, an SU app, and ditto for AskUbuntu, MathOverflow etc? Why? If I want to visit all of those sites on my phone, it will suffer from an App Overflow!

Comment: I knew SE really wants people to use their SO app for some reason (more downloads = more cash? To justify sunk costs before the management? Two icons on home screen = more awareness-building?), but crippling the SE app just to force users to download the part ripped out from it is going too far if that's what it is.

Comment: @MrLister - sounds like it's a "wide-box" strategy, where if you make product boxes wider, without putting more product in them, you can force competitors products off the shelf. A store has limited shelf space. If they want to stock 50 boxes of whatever, and those boxes take up more shelf space than they used to, there's less shelf space for competing brands. Memory for apps in a phone is limited; if you make your users install half-a-dozen apps instead of one there's less room for competing apps. Of course, I'm not aware of competitors for SO/SE, but whatever...