# Why maintain "Read this post in our app!" on SO mobile site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mobile-web

I was an avid SO android app user. But lately, shifted to SO mobile site because the official android app is far from a daily driver for me. There are many reasons to avoid it, [one of such is this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357688/tag-changes-not-getting-saved-while-editing-a-question)

But everytime I use SO mobile site, I'm greeted with a banner stating "Read this post in our app".

[image]

It would be sensible if the SO app was being maintained properly. But the last update it got was on **30 June 2017**!

[image]

Can it be removed completely from the mobile site? Clicking on [x] will dismiss it, but why still keep it there. 
 If the banner has to stay, can it be replaced with the [Stack Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) app or instead ask for user clarification as mentioned [in this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360143/mobile-site-read-this-post-in-our-app-works-only-with-stack-overflow). Though I prefer and recommend mobile site over Stack Exchange app.

Comment: 5 Months ago was the last update.  How does this indicate a lack of updates?  What is the expected update cycle?

Comment: I'm not an android app developer, but if I was to maintain an app I made for a website, I would believe to update or atleast fix **known** bugs. As a WinForms and WPF app developer I actively maintain my apps at regular intervals of 1 or 2 weeks after proper testing. I'm assuming SO has got many developers. Somebody could give it atleast a version bump, so as to let others know that app is still being looked after! Also I'm not stating to **remove the android app**. I'm suggesting to **remove or replace the banner link**

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358713/screen-rotation-discards-comment-drafts-and-creates-a-prompt-for-question-drafts#comment528183_358713.

Comment: @MikeM. I had seen it earlier. As I also commented in that post. Thanks anyways :). My suggestion here is to do something about "Read this post in our app!" banner

Comment: Yeah, I understand what this post is about. Just saying that it shouldn't be a surprise that the app hasn't been updated in a while. General FYI.

Comment: It would be nice if the mobile site could remember you clicking the "x" and not show the notification again.

Comment: @Chris. true that. But in my case, it remembers the choice sometimes. Maybe it has got something do with the cookies.

Comment: @StephenRauch Android and iOS apps basically have their development suspended. Kasra, IIRC the only Android dev moved along with the iOS devs to the DAG team. I don't think we'll see updates for a long, long while.

Comment: @Chris: Looking at [the code](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/mobile.en.js), it does remember that you've clicked the "x". It's implemented using LocalStorage, which makes it site (and browser) specific (so if you visit different SE sites, you'll have to dismiss the banner on each of them). Also, the banner apparently reappears 12 hours after you dismiss it the first time, 24 hours after the second time and 48 hours after the third time, before finally staying dismissed after you've closed it four times. Oh, and actually clicking the banner resets the counter.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Interesting.

Comment: I agree that the SO app isn't what we need. I do however like the idea of the link, if it can be changed to open the SE app instead. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359769/consider-the-stack-exchange-app-as-a-valid-app-to-view-stack-overflow-posts

Comment: @IlmariKaronen So if I’m clumsy and murphy applies, I will always reset the counter after the second time because I accidentally click the banner instead of the X. gotta love mobile UX.

Comment: Just use the desktop site. It doesn't show this and the mobile sites lacks the important features.

Comment: @VladimirF: either you really love pan and zoom, or have *really* great eyes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycCkG.jpg

Comment: @MatteoItalia It is still readable in your screenshot. I use doubletap and zoom. Almost never pan and zoom.